# Laravel Validator - Check if contain error key?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a validator like this,

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->query(),
    [
        'size'   => 'required|numeric|max:' . (100 * 1024 * 1024)
    ],
    [ 
        'size.required'   => 'param size is required',
        'size.numeric'    => 'param size should be numberic',
        'size.max'        => 'param size is over size'
    ]);
```

and now I want to check the `$validator` has error `size.required`

```
$messages = $validator->errors();
if ($messages->has('size.required')) {
    // do something...
} else if ($messages->has('size.numeric')) {
    // do something...
}
```

So is there a way to implement it?

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: You can't do that, `has` works with `size` not with `size.rule`. I can only think that you could use `get` instead of `has` (or `first`, so you only get the first error if you have multiple errors for the same field) and try to read the message and based on that, know what `rule` is not passing. Why do you want to do this ? Maybe the solution is in other place.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks a lot. I'm working on an API Laravel APP, so I want to response different error code by `Validator`'s result, for example, if rule `size.required` doesn't pass, it will response json like `{"error":30001,"message":"xxxxx"}` and if rule `size.numeric` doesn't pass, it will response json like `{"error":30002,"message":"xxxxx"}`. Is there a better way to do that? Thank you again.

Comment: i think you can do like this, if ($validation->fails()) {
            $messages = $validation->errors();
            if ($messages->has('size')) {
                if ($messages->first('size') == 'param size is required') {
                    // do something...
                } else if ($messages->first('size') == 'param size should be numberic') {
                    // do something...
                }
            }
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($messages);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Not a good solution but you can check if error message contains a keyword:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
 
if( Str::contains($messages->first('size'), 'required')){
    // do something..
}
```

Comment: As you say, yes it's not the best way to implement, but IT IS a solution. I will try it if there is really no better way. ANYWAY, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `failed` method in `Validation` class

```
$sizeArray = [
        'required' => '', //Required Validation Will Fail
        'numeric' => 'string', //Numeric Validation will fail
        'max' => (100 * 1024 * 1024 * 10),//max validation will fail
        'success_one' => '1234',
        'success_two' => 1234
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'size' => $sizeArray['numeric']
        ],
        [
            'size'   => 'required|numeric|max:' . (100 * 1024 * 1024)
        ],
        [
            'size.required'   => 'param size is required test manoj',
            'size.numeric'    => 'param size should be numberic',
            'size.max'        => 'param size is over size'
        ]
    );

    $validator->errors();//Don't Remove this line
    $failedValidation = collect($validator->failed())->map(function ($parameterFailedRules, $parameter) {
        return array_change_key_case($parameterFailedRules, CASE_LOWER);
    });

    if (Arr::has($failedValidation, 'size.required')) {
        dd('required Validation Failed');
    }else if(Arr::has($failedValidation, 'size.numeric')){
        dd('numeric Validation Failed');
    } else if (Arr::has($failedValidation, 'size.max')) {
        dd('max Validation Failed');
    }else{
        dd('All Validation Passed');
    }
```

Please Change the input value of `size` to change the error message.

Currently it will show .

> "numeric Validation Failed"